# All enemies destroyed when only one gets hit

Tags: unity, c#, collision-detection

I am trying to implement a new attack into my project. I can get the projectile to spawn and deal damage to an enemy, however, once it deals damage, every enemy gets destroyed instead of just the one that was hit. I am not using any static variables and I cannot figure out why this issue is happening.

Here is the projectile script:

```
 public GameObject HeavyExplosion;
 public GameObject LightExplosion;
 public float HeavyMissileSpeed = 1;
 public float LightMissileSpeed = 1;
 public float HeavyLaserSpeed;
 public float LightLaserSpeed;
 public float HeavyBulletSpeed;
 public float LightBulletSpeed;
 Rigidbody RB;
 public int HeavyMissileDamage;
 public int LightMissileDamage;
 public int HeavyLaserDamage;
 public int LightLaserDamage;
 public int HeavyBulletDamage;
 public int LightBulletDamage;
 public float ProjectileTimeout;
 float TimeElapsed;
 bool HasExploded;
 void Start()
 {
     RB = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
     HasExploded = false;
 }
 void Update()
 {
     TimeElapsed += Time.deltaTime;
     if(TimeElapsed >= ProjectileTimeout)
     {
         Destroy(gameObject);
     }
 }
 void FixedUpdate()
 {
     if (gameObject.CompareTag("HeavyMissile") && !HasExploded)
     {
         RB.velocity = HeavyMissileSpeed * gameObject.transform.forward;
     }
     if (gameObject.CompareTag("LightMissile") && !HasExploded)
     {
         RB.velocity = LightMissileSpeed * gameObject.transform.forward;
     }
     if (gameObject.CompareTag("HeavyLaser"))
     {
         RB.velocity = HeavyLaserSpeed * gameObject.transform.forward;
     }
     if (gameObject.CompareTag("LightLaser"))
     {
         RB.velocity = LightLaserSpeed * gameObject.transform.forward;
     }
     if (gameObject.CompareTag("HeavyBullet"))
     {
         RB.velocity = HeavyBulletSpeed * gameObject.transform.forward;
     }
     if (gameObject.CompareTag("LightBullet"))
     {
         RB.velocity = LightBulletSpeed * gameObject.transform.forward;
     }
 }
 private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
 {
     if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Enemy") && gameObject.CompareTag("HeavyMissile"))
     {
         collision.transform.parent.GetComponent<EnemyHealth>().DealDamage(HeavyMissileDamage);
         GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().enabled = false;
         GetComponent<Collider>().enabled = false;
         RB.velocity = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
         Instantiate(HeavyExplosion, transform);
         HasExploded = true;
         Destroy(gameObject, 1);
     }
     else if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Enemy") && gameObject.CompareTag("LightMissile"))
     {
         collision.transform.parent.GetComponent<EnemyHealth>().DealDamage(LightMissileDamage);
         GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().enabled = false;
         GetComponent<Collider>().enabled = false;
         RB.velocity = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
         Instantiate(LightExplosion, transform);
         HasExploded = true;
         Destroy(gameObject, 1);
     }
     else if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Enemy") && gameObject.CompareTag("HeavyLaser"))
     {
         collision.transform.parent.GetComponent<EnemyHealth>().DealDamage(HeavyLaserDamage);
         Destroy(gameObject);
     }
     else if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Enemy") && gameObject.CompareTag("LightLaser"))
     {
         collision.transform.parent.GetComponent<EnemyHealth>().DealDamage(LightLaserDamage);
         Destroy(gameObject);
     }
     else if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Enemy") && gameObject.CompareTag("HeavyBullet"))
     {
         collision.transform.parent.GetComponent<EnemyHealth>().DealDamage(HeavyBulletDamage);
         Destroy(gameObject);
     }
     else if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Enemy") && gameObject.CompareTag("LightBullet"))
     {
         collision.transform.parent.GetComponent<EnemyHealth>().DealDamage(LightBulletDamage);
         Destroy(gameObject);
     }
     else
     {
         Destroy(gameObject);
     }
 }
 private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
 {
     if (other.CompareTag("Enemy") && gameObject.CompareTag("HeavyMissile"))
     {
         other.transform.parent.GetComponent<EnemyHealth>().DealDamage(HeavyMissileDamage);
         GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().enabled = false;
         GetComponent<Collider>().enabled = false;
         RB.velocity = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
         Instantiate(HeavyExplosion, transform);
         HasExploded = true;
         Destroy(gameObject, 1);
     }
     else if (other.CompareTag("Enemy") && gameObject.CompareTag("LightMissile"))
     {
         other.transform.parent.GetComponent<EnemyHealth>().DealDamage(LightMissileDamage);
         GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().enabled = false;
         GetComponent<Collider>().enabled = false;
         RB.velocity = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
         Instantiate(LightExplosion, transform);
         HasExploded = true;
         Destroy(gameObject, 1);
     }
     else if (other.CompareTag("Enemy") && gameObject.CompareTag("HeavyLaser"))
     {
         other.transform.parent.GetComponent<EnemyHealth>().DealDamage(HeavyLaserDamage);
         Destroy(gameObject);
     }
     else if (other.CompareTag("Enemy") && gameObject.CompareTag("LightLaser"))
     {
         other.transform.parent.GetComponent<EnemyHealth>().DealDamage(LightLaserDamage);
         Destroy(gameObject);
     }
     else if (other.CompareTag("Enemy") && gameObject.CompareTag("HeavyBullet"))
     {
         other.transform.parent.GetComponent<EnemyHealth>().DealDamage(HeavyBulletDamage);
         Destroy(gameObject);
     }
     else if (other.CompareTag("Enemy") && gameObject.CompareTag("LightBullet"))
     {
         other.transform.parent.GetComponent<EnemyHealth>().DealDamage(LightBulletDamage);
         Destroy(gameObject);
     }
 }
```

Here is the enemy health script:

```
     public int MaxHealth = 1;
     int HP;
 
     public GameObject Explosion;
     public EnemySpawnerEternal SpawnReference { get; set; }
 
     void Awake()
     {
         HP = MaxHealth;
     }
 
     public void DealDamage(int Damage)
     {
         HP -= Damage;
         if(HP <= 0)
         {
             if(SpawnReference != null)
             {
                 SpawnReference.ResartSpawner();
             }
             GameObject.Instantiate(Explosion, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
             Destroy(gameObject);
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Which of these scripts is on which game objects?

Comment: @Ceriac When you include full classes in your question, it makes the question a little easier to read and discuss when you include the class headers, e.g. `public class EnemyHealth : MonoBehaviour {`

Comment: Unrelated to your question, you can simplify this code by a factor of six or more by not storing every possible speed/damage value on each projectile. Just store the value *for that one projectile type*. Then you can spawn a different prefab depending on the projectile you want, with that one damage variable set to the appropriate amount for that type.

Comment: @Philipp - The projectile behavior script is on the projectiles that get spawned in, and the enemy health script is on all enemies.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a guess, but based on my experience with pooling:

You have this line in your enemy health script:

```
SpawnReference.ResartSpawner();
```

I'm guessing that `EnemySpawnerEternal` is some type of spawn-pool system. Perhaps calling `RestartSpawner()` returns all spawned objects to the pool?

Comment: There is another attack that the player can perform that doesn't cause this issue. That script uses CompareTag("Enemy") and other.transform.parent.GetComponent<EnemyHealth>().DealDamage() and doesn't cause this issue.

Comment: @Ceriac Did you try commenting out the line of code that restarts the spawner, just to be sure?